# How do I specify <ALL FILES> in jee 7 permissions.xml

Tags: java, java-ee-7, wildfly-10

I have a JAXRS web application that is being deployed to a Wildfly 10 standalone server.  I am trying to create a restrictive META-INF/permissions.xml security policy in my war file, but I am struggling to get the java.io.FilePermission to recognize a property expansion.  When I use it in a .policy file, this works fine:

```
permission java.io.FilePermission       "${myProperty}", "read,write,execute";
```

But, when I port it to the permissions.xml, it generates a java.security.AccessControlException:

```
<permission>
   <class-name>java.io.FilePermission</class-name>
   <name>${myProperty}</name>
   <actions>read,write,execute</actions>
</permission>
```

or

```
<permission>
    <class-name>java.io.FilePermission</class-name>
    <name>${myProperty}${/}-</name>
    <actions>read,write,execute</actions>
 </permission>
```

or

```
<permission>
   <class-name>java.io.FilePermission</class-name>
   <name>&amp;lt;&amp;lt;ALL FILES&amp;gt;&amp;gt;</name>
   <actions>read,write,execute</actions>
</permission>
```

or

```
<permission>
   <class-name>java.io.FilePermission</class-name>
   <name>*</name>
   <actions>read,write,execute</actions>
</permission>
```

I can't seem to get it to work.  All of the above combinations fail.

Is there a way to make Property Expansion work in the permissions.xml?
Is there a way to make `<ALL FILES>` FilePermission work in the permissions.xml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
<permission>
   <class-name>java.io.FilePermission</class-name>
   <name>&lt;&lt;ALL FILES&gt;&gt;</name>
   <actions>read,write,execute</actions>
</permission>
```

?

Comment: That did it.  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks. I just have a silly question how can I verify that this permission policy has applied successfully?